# Plan Cache: Why are multiple plans cached for this stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, plan-cache

I am trying to gain a better understanding as to how SQL Server caches query plans.

For the following table(Populated with the values 1-500,000):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] ([ID] INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

And the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestGet]
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN;
    IF(@ID IS NOT NULL) BEGIN;
        SELECT [ID]
        FROM [dbo].[Test]
        WHERE [ID] = @ID;
    END;
    ELSE BEGIN;
        SELECT [ID]
        FROM [dbo].[Test];
    END;
END;
```

Making the following two calls:

```
EXEC [dbo].[TestGet] @ID = 1000;
EXEC [dbo].[TestGet] @ID = NULL;
```

Results in two different plans in the query plan cache:

[image: Plan Cache]

If the stored procedure were re-written as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestGet]
    @ID INT
AS
BEGIN;
    SELECT [ID]
    FROM [dbo].[Test]
    WHERE [ID] = @ID OR @ID IS NULL;
END;
```

And the same two calls were made:

```
EXEC [dbo].[TestGet] @ID = 1000;
EXEC [dbo].[TestGet] @ID = NULL;
```

Only a single query_hash, and query_plan_hash are cached:

[image]

The calls to the stored procedure have the same shape in both cases.  Why does one the first stored procedure and call generate two cached plans, with a different query_hash, and a different query_plan_hash?  What criteria is SQL Server using to generate these hashes?

Comment: Because the entire batch is compiled regardless of the parameters passed in, and both queries need to be identifiable. See [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185252/sql-server-if-logic-in-stored-procedure-and-the-plan-cache).

Comment: sp_BlitzErik - Is that also to say the number of cached plans will potentially be equal to the number of statements contained inside a condition, and that a plan will only be cached once a statement within a condition is executed.  Tangent question, for the pattern provided(@ID = scalar or @ID IS NULL) is there any benefit in separating the conditions into their own stored procedures, one for a scalar case and one for the NULL case?

Comment: @M.Jacobson If you have another question, please post it. Comments aren't a great place to go back and forth a bunch.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik - Thanks for the meta guidance.